# Status and visibility can not be set after copying a product programmatically?

Tags: magento2, product

Magento 2.4.6

I copied a product like that:

```
$childCopy = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier');
$childCopy = $childCopy->copy($parent);
```

This works, I can set the SKU, the URL key and so on on the `$childCopy`, but visibility and status do not work:

```
$childCopy->setSku('whatsever'); // works
$childCopy->setPrice(10); // works
$childCopy->setStatus(1); // does NOT work
$childCopy->setVisibility(1); // does NOT work
$childCopy->save();
```

Setting visibility and status only works when I set their scope to global, which I do not want to do. I am sure there is something I forgot to set ... and ideas? Using a product repository does not solve the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To properly set the visibility and status of a copied product in Magento without setting their scope to global, you can follow these steps:

**1)Inject the \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface and \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository classes into your constructor or method:**

```
protected $productAttributeInterface;
protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface $productAttributeInterface,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
) {
    $this->productAttributeInterface = $productAttributeInterface;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

**2)Use the $productRepository instance to load the copied product and set the visibility and status:**

```
$childCopy = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier');
$childCopy = $childCopy->copy($parent);

$childCopy->setSku('whatever');
$childCopy->setPrice(10);

$childCopy->setCustomAttribute('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$childCopy->setCustomAttribute('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);

$this->productRepository->save($childCopy);
```

In this example, we use the setCustomAttribute() method to set the status and visibility attributes, rather than the setStatus() and setVisibility() methods. The setCustomAttribute() method allows you to set attributes that are not directly exposed by the product model.

**By setting the status attribute to \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED and the visibility attribute to \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH, you can achieve the desired visibility and status for the copied product.**

*Remember to replace $objectManager with the dependency injection approach I mentioned earlier for creating the $childCopy instance. Avoid using the ObjectManager directly, as it's considered a bad practice in Magento.*

Comment: Thanks, doesnt work either ... same result, nothing changed, very strange!